# AWK passing ENV variables

Tags: awk

I have the following code to pass ENV variables to AWK.

```
  awk 'function pr(sp, k, v){    # prints key-value pair with indentation
         printf "%s\047%s\047: \047%s\047,\n",sp,k,v; 
     }
    BEGIN {
    db_user = ENVIRON["DB_USER"]
    db_pass = ENVIRON["DB_PASS"]
    db_name = ENVIRON["DB_NAME"]
    }
     /sqlite/{ sub(/sqlite[0-9]*/,"mysql",$0) }
     /NAME/{ sp=substr($0,1,index($0,"\047")-1); 
             print sp$1" \047db_name\047,"; 
             pr(sp,"USER", db_user); pr(sp,"PASSWORD", db_pass); 
             pr(sp,"HOST","localhost"); pr(sp,"PORT",""); next 
     }1'
```

I can get the db_name to be replaced with the ENV variable.

```
db_name = django
```

**My results are:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'django',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
      }
}
```

Comment: What is _not_ working then?

Comment: print sp$1" \047db_name\047,"; does not pass Django a the value, but simply passes db_name

Comment: @Ankh2054: Yes because the string to `print` is totally within quotes, the variable value is not expanded. Use `printf`

Comment: gosh thanks, been looking at code for too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is *incorrect* use of `print` statement in `Awk`. As seen from this [GNU Awk `print()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Print-Examples.html) page, you need to move the variable outside the quotes to see its expanded value.

```
print sp$1" \047db_name\047,"; 
#               ^^^^^^^ Awk does not understand db_name  within quotes
```

Just make it outside the quotes as below.

```
print sp$1" \047"db_name"\047,"
```

(or) Use `printf` altogether to separate the format specifiers from the variables and do as below

```
printf "%s %s \047%s\047,\n",sp,$1,db_name
```